# Datagridview PSARgumentNullException

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell, datagridview

I have this error in a `DataGridView` that I don't understand.

It happens when I scroll the datagrid (which is bound to a collection).

[image]

I don't get what it means since everything in the datagrid is a string.

It says "unable to process argument because value of argument "component" is null". What does that mean ?

I bind the grid this way :

```
$Button.Add_Click({
    $szone = $comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
    $Mzone = $comboBox1.SelectedItem[0].ToString()
    $FinalObject = SearchEngine $Mzone $szone 
    $list = [system.Collections.ArrayList]($FinalObject.result)
    $dataGridView.Datasource = $list
    $Form1.Refresh()
})
```

with a bit of investigation i success catch the error with this

```
$dataGridView.Add_DataError({
write-host $_.Context.ToString()
})
```

but it not explain well whats wrong it just throw
Display
Display
Display

in console like its a display error but it not help much what to do...

Comment: Have you tried to put a `try/catch` around this code to get to know what is `null`?

Comment: no but the error will be the same anyway in console i guess. + i'm not able to try/catch when i scroll the datagrid its internal to winform

Comment: You need to look up what is `null` , my French is not very good so I can't tell you from the exception message.

Comment: Have you tried the methods and properties listed here to know more about the error ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewdataerroreventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. `Context` = state of the `DataGridView` at the time of the exception, `Exception` = exception data, `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` = the cell in which the data error occurred.

Comment: At final it was realy insolvable powershell 2.0 is hella bugy. I solved this using a large function to convert properly PsObject into Datatable then binding the datatable to datagridview don't genere any data error